# How can I store large text+image blog posts in MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I have got a problem because I am making a simple blog using Spring Boot/Data/Security and MongoDB. How can I store blog posts that can consist of many images and text (Above 16mb which is the limit) in MongoDB? Is there any way to do this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: [GridFS](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.4/driver/tutorials/gridfs/) will help you get started.

Comment: I checked that and I found many tutorials on how to upload a file/an image to GridFS but I do not really know how to store firstly created posts,I mean they contain Both text and images and they are not stored on my drive. I am sorry if this question is really stupid but I am totally new to MongoDB and NoSQL databases

Comment: Np. The current post is too broad to answer. I would recommend reading mongodb [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/crud/) and  understand how to use the product first and once basics are out of way, you can come back and ask specific questions.